# Load DIV tag from external file

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get rid of the FRAME tag by trying to load a DIV tag when a link is selected in my NavBar (what used to load "file1.html" target="ContentFrame"). I now have the single page divided into two DIV tags. The top DIV tag is my navbar which works perfectly loading html files into a FRAME, but now I'm trying to instead load the HTML file (after removing all the extra HTML tags like HTML, HEAD, BODY, etc...) into a second DIV tag called "Content". I've looked into jQuery .Load, but can't seem to get that to work like I want. I was considering looking into PHP instead now. I'm really open to suggestions on what to look for, or any example source that might do something like I want. Any ideas?

```
<!-- NavBar -->
<a href="body1.html">Load body1.html into DIV ID Content</a>
<a href="body2.html">Load body2.html into DIV ID Content</a>

<div id="Content">
  Contents of body1.html would be here when page is first loaded.
  Then the contents here would be loaded from the file in the anchor
  tag when a link is selected. The bodyX.html files would have tags
  within them as well. Not just text.
</div>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $("a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#Content").load(this.href, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr.status)})
        })
        .filter("[href=http://www.gddas.com/newsite/home.html]").click()
      })
    </script>       
    <title>Index Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="images/logos/GDDASLogo.png" width="274" height="133" alt="GDDAS Logo" /><br>
      <ul class="flex">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li> <!-- This had the full path, but that didn't make a difference -->
        <li><a href="officers.html">Officers</a></li>
        <li><a href="announce.html"</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="education.html">Continuing Ed</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the code you've tried. .load() is the solution your looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Include</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#link1">Link1</a>
    <a href="#link2">Link2</a>
    <a href="#link3">Link3</a>
    <a href="#link4">Link4</a>


    <div id="include"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var includeDiv = $("#include");
        $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
            var href = location.hash.slice(1) +".html";
            includeDiv.load('include/' + href);
        });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: That works near perfectly! The only missing part would be to start off with home.html loaded in the include div. Any ideas on that part?

Comment: creating the style of CSS for the home.html loaded in the include div

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand. Are you saying that I should add a tag in the CSS file that would load home.html on first open? If so, which tag would that be?

Comment: Is there anyone else that can expand on this? The code above is working great, except that "home.html" should be loaded in the "include" id when the page is first loaded and it isn't. In fact, even if I click on the "Home" link after it's loaded, it won't show the page. If I click on any other link that one loads correctly, then clicking on Home after that will show Home. Any help would be greatly appreciated!'

Comment: You can use the same type of code but within a $(document).ready(). For example: `$(document).ready( function() { includeDiv.load('include/home.html'); });` Right at the end of the js script.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to .php extensions, and if your main file for example is called "index.php" create two other files with the contents of the two divs (for example: div1.php and div2.php

Based on the above, your index.php should look similar to that:

```
<html>
<head>
..... head here
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<?php include('div1.php'); ?>
</div>
<div id="div2">
<?php include('div2.php'); ?>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

Very basic and unpolished example but should give you a point to start...

UPDATE:

First check out this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vc2nq3us/3/

This is not working of course since ajax is not included in my fiddle. You can just use this code for your project and will be ok...

Now, there is one more file involved -not showing in jsfiddle. It can be something like that:

```
<?php

//protect the file from un-authorized access
define('AJAX_REQUEST', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!AJAX_REQUEST) {die();}

if(isset($_POST["fileid"])){$fileid = $_POST["fileid"];}else{$fileid = ""; exit();} //if no fileid is set, kill the script

$file_contents = file_get_contents($fileid.".html"); //here we fetch the contents of file (for example: 1.html or 2.html and so on...)

echo htmlentities($file_contents); 

?>
```

Hope this works for you... T.

Comment: That looks good. Except how would I change the contents of div2 based on a link being clicked? I'll update my q with some pseudo code.

Comment: That can be done nicely with ajax and has a different approach. I will prepare you a fiddle and get back to you

Comment: @user2021539 I have prepared a fiddle for you to look at. It contains three variables with 3 different possible contents for div 2 (selectable by button).
These variables could also be contents of files which can be fetched by using ajax. (in this case contents can change in your div without even refreshing the page)... check out this fiddle and if you think that it is a possible solution for you, I can send you the complete ajax code -because it is not in allowed in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vc2nq3us/1/

Comment: This update loads the contents of the first variable immediately after page loads: http://jsfiddle.net/vc2nq3us/2/

Comment: I think that might work. But is the data being read from the html file or the var? Because the actual page has about 30 links and each linked html file has formatting tags, and s4everal of the pages have 3+ pages worth of text and IMG tags.

Comment: the variable represents the contents of a file. You can select which file you want according to the parameters you pass to ajax. Ajax reads the content of the desired file, stores it into a variable and then this var is loaded into the div.

Comment: Ok, great! That looks like it should work then. I'll just have to work out how to change it from an onclick of a button to an onclick of an anchor.

Comment: Ok, kinda' got lost on the additional file. Would this be a php file that should be included on the html file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90185/discussion-between-captain-theo-and-user2021539).

Comment: Yes this is a php file. It is not included in any other file. It is just being called by ajax. Just create it and save it to the same working folder as the other files

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.click()` , `.preventDefault()` , `href` of clicked `a` element within handler

```
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#Content").load(this.href)
  })
  // load `body1.html` into `#Content` at page load
  .filter("[href^=body1]").click()
})
```

Comment: Plus 1. I don't think he needs the `.filter('...').click ()` part but this is still "the answer"

Comment: This looks good too. But where would this function be defined? Using a SCRIPT tag in the body?

Comment: @user2021539 _"But where would this function be defined? Using a SCRIPT tag in the body? "_ Yes. Could also try `script` tag within `head` element

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I added the SCRIPT tag in the header section. And at least the preventdefault seems to be working. But there is no data added to the Content id. which is just div id="content"

Comment: @user2021539 Are contents of `html` files full document e.g., `<!DOCTYPE html><html>..</html>` or `html` fragment, e.g., `<div>..</div>` ?

Comment: Fragments. No HTML, HEAD or BODY tags.

Comment: Tried substituting full path to file for "body1.html" at `a` `href` ?

Comment: Try adding callback to `.load()` , `$("#Content").load(this.href, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr.status)})` what  does `console` log ?

Comment: @user2021539 Can include full `html` , including `js` at OP ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90187/discussion-between-user2021539-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why jquery.load is not working for you. Posting your efforts on that could be more beneficial.

Here is the documentation on it, it should work:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Below: The selector is where you want to put the contents of the file. The parameter within the .load() is the path to the file.

```
$( "#Content" ).load( "file1.html" );
```

Comment: I don't think .load will work for me because it is in <head> section and I need to change the contents based on an anchor click in the body section.

Answer (score 0):

You wrong to use `#Content` try using `#content` instead :

```
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load(this.href);
  })
  .filter("[href^=body1]").click();
});
```